# Map string array into individual arrays

Tags: arrays, api, mule, dataweave

I am trying to manipulate my payload for a bulk API message body where I am updating multiple images at the same time. For example here I have two images:

```
[
  {
    "entry": {
      "media_type": "image",
      "position": [
        "1",
        "2"
      ],
      "disabled": false,
      "types": {
        "image",
      "small_image",
      "thumbnail"
      },
      "content": {
        "base64_encoded_data": [
          "/9j/4ReLRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgA....",
         "/9j/4ReLRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgA...."],
"type": "image/jpeg",
        "name": [
          "228186_1.jpg",
          "228187_2.jpg"
        ]
      },
      "sku": [
        "228186",
        "228187"
     ]
}
}
]
```

but I need these to appear as two separate entries below each other... how can split this into into individual entries so that for position and sku etc it only shows one entry? eventually i will want to use this to list data for several images below each other to update the via bulk API.

This is my desired output

```
[
{
"entry": {
"media_type": "image",
"disabled": false,
"position": 1,
"types": [
"image",
"small_image",
"thumbnail"
],
"content": {
"base64EncodedData":  ["/9j/4ReLRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgA....],
"type": "image/png",
"name": "228186_1.jpg"
}
},
"sku": "228186"
},
{
"entry": {
"media_type": "image",
"disabled": false,
"position": 2,
"types": [
"image",
"small_image",
"thumbnail"
],
"content": {
"base64EncodedData":  ["/9j/4ReLRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgA....],
"type": "image/jpeg,
"name": "228187_2.jpg"
}
},
"sku": "228187"
}
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is all kinds of invalid JSON in your example.. can you provide an example output?

Comment: In addition to what @MichaelJones mentioned, the example has base64 content for a single image. It seem the second image is missing.

Comment: thanks @MichaelJones I have added my desired output. I have tried your solution but it still lists two entries under position, sku and name and hasn't split the payload into two

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Making the same assumption as Michael Jones for payload a more precise one by preserving the order

If your input is an array of object, please use this:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::util::Values
output application/json
---
flatten(payload map(v1, k1) ->
    (v1.entry.position) map(v2, k2) ->
    entry:{
        "media_type": v1.entry.media_type,
        "position": v1.entry.position[k2],
        "disabled":v1.entry.disabled,
        "types": v1.entry.types,
        "content": {
            "base64_encoded_data": v1.entry.content.base64_encoded_data,
            "type": v1.entry.content."type",
            "name": v1.entry.content.name[k2]
        },
        "sku": v1.entry.sku[k2]
})
```

Please note that in your input for "types" you have given as

```
"types": {
        "image",
      "small_image",
      "thumbnail"
}
```

An object of strings, which is not correct. An object will always have key and value, So I am assuming it to be like this:

```
"types": [
        "image",
      "small_image",
      "thumbnail"
]
```

---

If your input is an object of objects, you can use this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var indices = payload.entry.position map ($ as Number) - 1
---
indices map entry:{
    (payload.entry - "content" - "sku" - "position" - "disabled" - "types"),
    position: payload.entry.position[$],
    (payload.entry - "content" - "sku" - "position" - "media_type" - "types"),
    (payload.entry - "content" - "sku" - "position" - "disabled" - "media_type"),
    content: {
        base64_encoded_data: payload.entry.content.base64_encoded_data[$],
        "type": payload.entry.content."type",
        name: payload.entry.content.name[$]
    },
    sku: payload.entry.sku[$]
}
```

Comment: thank you Amer, I have tried that but the error I now get is

org.mule.runtime.core.internal.message.ErrorBuilder$ErrorImplementation
{
  description="Cannot coerce Array (["1", "2"]) to Number

3| var indices = payload.entry.position map ($ as Number) - 1
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^
Trace:
  at main (line: 3, column: 43), while writing Json at 
3| var indices = payload.entry.position map ($ as Number) - 1
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^.

Comment: I have edited my solution please check it

Comment: Thanks so much Amer, your first option for array of objects has worked perfectly for me! Thank you for your help and patience!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant your payload to look like this, and I'm taking some guesses here...

```json
{
   "entry":{
      "media_type":"image",
      "position":[
         "1",
         "2"
      ],
      "disabled":false,
      "types":[
         "image",
         "small_image",
         "thumbnail"
      ],
      "content":{
         "base64_encoded_data":[
            "/9j/4ReLRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgA....",
            "/9j/8ReLRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgA...."
         ],
         "type":"image/jpeg",
         "name":[
            "228186_1.jpg",
            "228187_2.jpg"
         ]
      },
      "sku":[
         "228186",
         "228187"
      ]
   }
}
```

And then also guessing on the shape of your desired output...

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var indices = payload.entry.position map ($ as Number) - 1
---
indices map {
    (payload.entry - "content" - "sku" - "position"),
    position: payload.entry.position[$],
    content: {
        base64_encoded_data: payload.entry.content.base64_encoded_data[$],
        "type": payload.entry.content."type",
        name: payload.entry.content.name[$]
    },
    sku: payload.entry.sku[$]
}
```

What I'm ensure about is if we can rely on the position object to be their positions in the payload, or to mean something else. You could also change it to something like `var indices = 0 to sizeOf(payload.entry.position) - 1`

Creates:

```json
[
  {
    "media_type": "image",
    "position": "1",
    "disabled": false,
    "types": [
      "image",
      "small_image",
      "thumbnail"
    ],
    "content": {
      "base64_encoded_data": "/9j/4ReLRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgA....",
      "type": "image/jpeg",
      "name": "228186_1.jpg"
    },
    "sku": "228186"
  },
  {
    "media_type": "image",
    "position": "2",
    "disabled": false,
    "types": [
      "image",
      "small_image",
      "thumbnail"
    ],
    "content": {
      "base64_encoded_data": "/9j/8ReLRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgA....",
      "type": "image/jpeg",
      "name": "228187_2.jpg"
    },
    "sku": "228187"
  }
]
```